# Why is the critical section not working as a mutex?

Tags: mutex, critical-section

with the mutex, the threads are executed alternately, but with the critical section it's not at all like that.

```
#include "stdafx.h" 
#include <windows.h> 
#include <iostream> 
#include <omp.h>
using namespace std;

int global = 100;
HANDLE ht1, ht2; 
CRITICAL_SECTION cs;
DWORD WINAPI ThreadProc1(LPVOID lpParameter ) { 
    int i, j;   
    for (j=1; j <= 12; j++)    {        
        EnterCriticalSection(&cs);   
        i = global;      
        i++;     
        Sleep (1);      
        global = i; 
        printf_s( "%4s %4d \n", " 1 th", i );     
        LeaveCriticalSection(&cs);   
    } 
    return 0;  
}
DWORD WINAPI ThreadProc2 (LPVOID lpParameter) { 
    int i, j; 
    for (j=1; j <= 12; j++)    {    
        EnterCriticalSection(&cs);   
        i = global;      
        i++;     
        Sleep (1);     
        global = i;
        printf_s( "%4s %4d %4d \n", " 2 th", i, j );     
        LeaveCriticalSection(&cs);    
    } 
    return 0; 
} 
int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[]) { 
    HANDLE msh[2]; 
    InitializeCriticalSection(&cs);
    ht1 = CreateThread(NULL, 0, &ThreadProc1, NULL, 0, NULL); 
    ht2 = CreateThread(NULL, 0, &ThreadProc2, NULL, 0, NULL); 
    msh[0] = ht1; 
    msh[1] = ht2;
    Sleep(500);
    DeleteCriticalSection(&cs);
    return 0; 
}
```

I get this result
https://i.stack.imgur.com/n9ISP.png

with mutex, the result is normal, I expected the same result for the critical section
https://i.stack.imgur.com/OGm5N.png

Comment: Seems like `std::mutex` implements a fifo on your system. I'd actually expect the behavior you get from the critical section.

Comment: @tkausl I thought that the second thread would wait for the LeaveCriticalSection () to execute the first thread, and then go to the critical section.

Comment: It does wait at the `EnterCriticalSection` but then yields as it has nothing to do. The other thread releases the critical section and loops again, and since its still running and the other thread is not scheduled currently, it immediately gets the critical section again.